# Error when creating folder in google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have search in th enet but i can't find the solutions. Please help. Below is the code.

```
    <?php 

require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Drive API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY)
));

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setAccessType('offline');


$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'Test Folder',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);die();


?>
```

I can list all the files from the drive but I can't create a folder. What I'm missing? Below is the error. Can someone help me to solve this problem of mine. Thanks in advance.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will assist you in solving your problem, I found your error here: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors

To help you navigate to a solution, here is the snippet, hope this assists you in some way:

**401: Invalid Credentials
Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid.**

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

**Suggested action: Refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in Authorizing Your App with Google Drive.**

If you want to know more about Authorizing your app with google drive, please refer to this site:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth

Hope you are able to find a solution with the resources provided.

Comment: I have modified the code. I have already access the google drive because I can list all the files from the GDrive. But when I create a new folder. An error occurred.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}